# Passing data from multiple forms to one single form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to pass details of multiple forms that all lead up to one form? 
I want that each time i click that button that leads to the next form, show the details from the form it came from.
I have multiple forms such as newclient, updateclient and transactions that use the billing form. and I want to know if I could pass the details of each of those forms to the billing form?

Comment: it's possible to do this are you familiar with `MDI` are you familiar with Classes and how to use them, Interfaces and how to use them? this can be done several ways .. can you elaborate on what you have tried thus far..?

Comment: If you want to do a "hack" version of this, if you are not planning on remembering the data when the person reopens the form etc then you can do something pretty simple. 

When you are creating a new form just pass through the values you want from the current form, you will just need to overload the constructor for the form eg.

Button code
     private void ButtonClick()
     {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2(string data1, string data2);
            form2.Show();
     }

Then your other form code would look something like 

     public Form2(string data1, string data2)
     {

     }

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing what I said above if you want good quality code but if you want a quick solution it can be done like that.

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure the downvotes are coming from a lack of apparent effort in your question. You should include what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, with many implementations available.

For one, you could store the previous view model as a property of the new view model. Here's how it would look from the NewClient post action in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewClient(NewClientModel newClientModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // handle validation
    }

    var billingModel = new BillingModel
    {
        NewClientModel = newClientModel
    };

    return RedirectToAction("Billing", billingModel);
}
```

In this case, the BillingModel could look something like this:

```
public class BillingModel
{
    public NewClientModel NewClientModel { get; set; }

    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }

    // etc...
}
```

Then, in the Billing view you would simply display both:

```
@model BillingModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NewClientModel.Whatever)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomeOtherProperty)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this *procedure* :

1. In all forms, declare the variables which of them you want to move

   ```
   public static string Name = "";
   public static string Name2 = "";
   ```

   in `button_click` event or other event

   ```
   Name = comboBox1.Text;
   Name2 = textBox1.Text;
   ```
2. In the form where all data is to be moved to the Load event, write them

   ```
   textBox1.Text = Form1.Name;
   label12.Text = Form3.Name2;
   ```